# AngularFire2: Notify Sign-out Across Multiple Browser Tabs

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm working on an Angular application which is hooked up to Firebase. If I have 2 instances of the app in a browser and log out from one, how do I notify the other instance that the user is no longer authenticated and should unsubscribe from Firebase.

I have provided a stackblitz which subscribes to a real instance of the Firebase. When clicked on `sign in`, it logs in and fetches a document.  This recreates the scenario, but since it only outputs a log on the console, it still does not work as expected with the real project.

[Stackblitz. To recreate, open 2 instances of it, sign in one of them and signout.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/two-browsers)

Comment: Your do fires and the "signout" is printed to the console. So it is working. What is your question?

Comment: @RobinDijkhof On the stackblitz example, it does fire the "sign out" on console but in my project, when signed out from one instance on the browser, it unsubscribes from firebase. But the other instance is still subscribed and throws an error since it is not authenticated anymore. The second instance is not notified that the first is already signed out and unsubscribed.

So my question is, how do I unsubscribe from the second instance of the app as well, resulting in no fatal error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, as I can't reproduce the error. Although posting it anyway.

```
export class SomeComponentOrService{
    private subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth){
        this.subscription = afAuth.subscribe(res => {
            if(isNullOrUndefined(res){
                this.subscription.unsubscribe();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer of what might be the problem.

```
this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
```

`auth` is the current state. The current state might be null if the user is already signed out. A simple null check might fix your error.

```
if(!isNullOrUndefined(this.afAuth.auth){
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
}
```